# Notepad++ writes a lot to disk after closing

Tags: notepad++, disk-activity

I decided to open the disk usage statistics in Resource Monitor, and discovered that after closing `notepad++.exe`, even if there were no files open, a large write to the disk occurs. In the first second, the speed is approximately 4 MB/s, then less: 3 MB, 1 MB, 500 KB, 300 KB, 100 KB. And in total it writes like this for about a minute. I think the total write will be at least 30 MB.

`notepad.exe` writes to both files “e:\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml” (which is 10 KB) and “e:\User\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\session.xml” (which is 200 bytes).

I have the same problem with Classic Shell, but I decided to write about Notepad++, since it is easier to explain and test. Does your Notepad++ also writes to disk when closed? I'm afraid my Windows is broken.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Windows or Notepad++ : Mine does
exactly the same.

Notepad++ always writes its closing configuration to the file
`config.xml`, which serves for it to be able when launched
to open with exactly the same configuration as when you closed it.

As for the disk speeds, they don't mean much for such a small file.
The registered speed takes a few seconds to return to zero, not because
Windows is doing more writes, but because the previous write is
remembered for a very short time after it finishes.

Comment: Did you mean "previous write is remembered for a very **long** time after it finishes"?

Comment: The is defined by the sampling application, the frequency and algorithm used to calculate the results. If the sampling is every 5 seconds then you won't see any changes for 5 seconds, although no I/O is done, etc.

Comment: Correct. I have observed that if there is a small but quick write, resource monitor will initially show it as, for example, 5,000,000B/sec, then it'll decrease over 10-20 seconds until the name of the application disappears from the list. It absolutely does not mean that the application was writing anything all this time.

Comment: Note that this happens because displaying the correct speed at the time is at best confusing, so it gets averaged out over time. Try implementing something that displays "simply the value right now" and you'll see why it's done that way.

Comment: @bytepusher …It should at least be averaged spread out over the duration of each sample so it tells the truth if you numerically integrate it, not smeared out over multiple samples in this confusing way. The write speed graph and numbers I have on my taskbar and system monitor are perfectly readable as implemented.

Comment: Yes, it's not well handled. A deceptively "simple" problem though, not surprised the M$ peops have gotten this wrong. I was just trying to give a hint as to why "just the number" doesn't easily work

Comment: @websites He means that it is a very **short** time as the user perceives it, lasting for only a split second, not that it is a very long time compared to how long the write actually took place (which is also true).

Answer (score 9):

Notepad++, and many of its add-ons, are not efficient when it comes to disk writes on program termination.

Notepad++ itself writes its configuration file to disk every time you exit Notepad++, even if there have been no changes to its configuration.

Similarly, many of the plugins (extensions) for Notepad++ do the same.

If you have several Notepad++ plugins, the results can be a large number of disk writes when Notepad++ closes.

You may consider filing an issue report on the [Notepad++ GitHub repository](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues) if there isn't one already.

One solution is to run Notepad++ from a RAMisk.  I have tested this configuration and it makes Notepad++ open and close faster and definitely reduces drive wear and tear.

Comment: It's surprising that a program that is primarily concerned with editing (reading and writing) files, the developers put such little thought into its read/write performance optimization.  A simple dirty flag on the files would suffice.  For better read/write performance, using the file size to set the buffer size, say 1% minimum, would dramatically reduce read/write times on "large" files.

Comment: @AtesComp it's a tiny file, its probably not really worth the effort

Comment: @AlanBirtles When my Notepad++ closes, 7 files are written to, as there are also plugins.  Unfortunately, plugin developers have followed the lead of the mantra *"probably not really worth the effort"*.  The collective writing definitely has a noticeable performance impact, especially when you account for malware scanning.  If everyone considers their actions only in isolation, there is often little impact, but the impacts of our actions are rarely in isolation.

Comment: @AlanBirtles That's why "large" is in quotes. Also, this point make a better argument. I was jumping to solution. Thanks.

Comment: @End "definitely [..] noticeable"? Your plugins must be writing much more than a tiny file or you have a really old 5400rpm disk and misconfigured windows to not use its write cache or some other problem. 
Standard notepad++ takes a total of 30ms to close on my system. Any performance difference there is not something that would be noticeable.

Comment: @Voo In your conclusion, you are ignoring many pertinent facts: (1) programs do not work in isolation on systems, (2) unnecessary data written by plugins in line with the *"probably not really worth the effort"* mantra, (3) malware scanning that inspects files written to storage, (4) not everyone's system is as fast your system.  If you want to discuss more, please start a chat as comments are not for extended discussions.

Comment: @End Do you have an actual trace that shows a "definitely noticeable" slowdown (ie 200+ms)? That'd be interesting for perf analysis, although clearly if plugins are the culprit they'd have to do their own analysis.

Comment: @Voo As I previously wrote, if you want to discuss more, please start a chat as comments are not for extended discussions.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at closing of (my copy of) Notepad++ with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), it writes to 3 files:

- plugins\config\XMLTools.ini - presumably by [XMLTools plugin](https://github.com/morbac/xmltools). It writes 1.2KB, though it writes every line separately.
- config.xml - 11KB
- session.xml - 2KB